# How to Scroll textbox automatically in Scrollviewer when press left/right arrow keys?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, horizontal-scrolling

I am wrapping the textbox with scrollerviewer. The problem is when there is enough text to scroll horizontally, and we use the left/right arrow to move through text, the cursor moves beyond the display area, but it doesn't auto scroll the content.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBox x:Name="Text1" AcceptsReturn="True" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="150"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Any expert here?

Comment: I want to keep scrollviewer to wrap the textbox as scrollviewer has modified style. MinWidth seems playing some role here, but not sure what.

Comment: Below code change resolves the issue but introduces to new issue - Home and End keys now doesn't auto scroll:

    
`<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBox x:Name="Text1" AcceptsReturn="True" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="150" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
            </ScrollViewer>`

Answer (score 0):

Dont wrap your TextBox with a `ScrollViewer`. TextBox has already scrolling-support.

Do the following with your TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Text1" Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="150" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

Here an Example, that shows the difference:

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="300">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <TextBox x:Name="Text2" AcceptsReturn="True" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="150"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox x:Name="Text1" Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="150" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />

    </Grid>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply, below code also works, but when I use it in my COMPLEX application, it's not working as expected - so something with my N number of styles in application. I need to work on it.  

    <TextBox x:Name="Text1" AcceptsReturn="True" Width="150" Height="150" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" crollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

Comment: Can you give an example of your said complexity?